# Реализация pop_back для вектора

Tags: c++

Написала реализацию, но мне она не нравится. чтобы можно улучшить?

```
 template<typename T>
 void Vector<T>::PopBack()
 {
    if (mSize == mCapacity)
    {
       T* result = new T[mCapacity];
       for (decltype(mSize) i = 0; i < mSize; ++i)
         result[i] = mVector[i];
       delete[] mVector;
       mVector = result
    }
    mVector[--mSize]
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Улучшить ее можно просто: всю ее сделать одной строкой

```
--mSize;
```

Собственно, что вам нужно? просто указать, что элементов стало на один меньше. Зачем при этом уменьшать выделенную память? Пусть себе ждет вставки нового элемента... Ну и, конечно, нужно убедиться, что сам вектор в этот момент не пустой, т.е.

```
if (mSize) --mSize;
```

Другое дело - вызывать ли деструктор для элемента явно или оставить элемент как есть. Это зависит от того, как именно вы работаете с элементами - добавляете новый путем вызова конструктора копирования или при помощи присваивания.

Comment: да мне нужно  через деструктор удалять

Comment: Ну, тогда дополнительно удаляете вызовом деструктора, только учтите, что при удалении потом `delete[]mVector;` деструкторы будут вызваны повторно... Ну и в `push_back` вы тогда не должны использовать присваивание - потому что при этом опять же в этом элементе после деструктора уже **нет** нормального объекта.

Comment: а как мне вызывать  деструктор последнего элемента? который я  хочу удалить

Comment: @ОксанаВолинець, `mVector[mSize-1].~T();`

Answer (score 3):

Один из вариантов выглядит так:

```
template<typename T>
void Vector<T>::PopBack(){
     if(isEmpty()){
         return;
     }

     --mSize;
     mVector[mSize].~T();
}
```

Но если вы планируете вызывать деструктор явно, то вам следует пересмотреть алгоритм выделения/освобождения памяти. Так как `new T[]`/`delete[]` может привести к повторному вызову деструктора.

В общих чертах, это могло бы выглядеть так:

```
template<class T>
class Vector{
    int mSize;
    int mCapacity;
    T *mVector;
public:
    Vector():
        mSize(0),
        mCapacity(42),
        mVector(allocate(mCapacity))
    {}
    T* begin(){
        return mVector;
    }
    T* end(){
        return mVector + mSize;
    }
    bool isEmpty() const{
        return mSize == 0;
    }
    void popBack(){
        if(isEmpty()){
            return;
        }
        
        --mSize;
        destroy(end());
    }
    ~Vector(){
        for(T &object : *this){
            destroy(&object);
        }
        deallocate(mVector);
    }
private:
    static void construct(T *object){
        new(object) T;
    }
    static void destroy(T *object){
        object->~T();
    }
    static T* allocate(int count){
        return static_cast<T*>(malloc(count * sizeof(T)));
    }
    static void deallocate(void *ptr){
        free(ptr);
    }
};
```

Как видите, вся работа с выделением/освобождением памяти происходит в методах `allocate`/`deallocate`. В методе `allocate` выделяется кусок памяти при помощи `malloc`. В методе `deallocate` этот кусок памяти освобождается. Никаких  конструкторов и деструкторов автоматически не вызывается. Эти операции нам придется делать вручную. Для этих целей есть методы `construct`/`destroy`.

Конструктор, деструктор, и метод `popBack` в этом примере реализованы. Аналогично при помощи методов `allocate`, `deallocate`, `construct` и `destroy` можно реализовать остальные.

**P.S.** Кстати, примерно таким же образом работает с памятью стандартный вектор. Только у него все эти методы вынесены в отдельный класс [`std::allocator`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/allocator/?kw=allocator). Но вам для простоты можно объявить их прямо в теле вектора.